# Cisco AnyConnect VPN: no internet connection on browser only

Tags: vpn, internet-connection, cisco-vpn-client

I use Cisco AnyConnect VPN on a Windows 10 machine. It is a couple of months that once I install Cisco Anyconnect and then reboot the system I lose Internet on the browser only (i.e. Outlook, Spotify do work).

Switching to a different browser does not solve the problem (I have the latest versions of Chrome and Edge);
Disabling IPV6 does not work;
I do not have any conflicting program installed (e.g., Connectify... but I am not sure about NordVPN).

Internet works normally after uninstalling Cisco AnyConnect and rebooting again.

Comment: Check to see if you have proxy settings defined. That's one of the first thing I'd check for this sort of problem as you describe. I'd check both Chrome and IE web browser proxy settings too by the way.

Comment: I add a proxy switcher extension on Chrome (but not on Edge). I just removed it. Let me try to reboot anche check.

Comment: True, I had some proxy setting, however they were all disabled. It is now a bit better (it takes two reboots before internet on the browser goes). However, I noticed that the proxy address and port goes back after I reboot (despite still in a disabled mode). I am wondering where this file is located such that I can delete this information once for all.

Comment: Go to `inetcpl.cpl` from run and then press enter once typed, then go to **Connections | LAN settings | Proxy server** section, uncheck everything once you see and document what is configured in case you need to change it back.... https://i.imgur.com/9QGRABG.png

Comment: Also you can type in the [Windows search `proxy`, click on Proxy settings](https://i.imgur.com/auaGZZj.png) and then from there ensure the [proxy settings are not turned on in there](https://i.imgur.com/0Q7VmGr.png)

Comment: I managed to cleaned the proxy setting properly, but the problem is still there. If I install AnyConnect but do not connect to it the problem never appers. Once I run AnyConnect once and then reboot here I go without any browser internet.

Comment: There is not change in the settings when the connection does not work. The problme persists even when I use Google's DNS.

Comment: How about other network adapter configuration settings via `npca.cpl`? Check to ensure how they are classified and such too with and without problem. Are you able to ping google.com with and without the problem? How about `nslookup google.com` output results with and without problem. Don't forget about `route print` output and comparisons too. Keep digging, it has to be something. I assume you are not connected to Nord VPN and then connecting to a Cisco VPN or something odd like that, but to troubleshoot that sort of issue is probably too broad.

Comment: What AV and security software and/or software/OS firewall configurations do to have set? These are other things to check that could possibly be related somehow. Just think of everything and check everything and do basic troubleshooting 101 and double check all the basic and fundamental things. Process of elimination but may be factors in your environment too we just don't know about.